# Select2 use a dynamic Ajax URL on call

Tags: jquery-select2, jquery-select2-3

I use the Select2 plugin (v 3.5.2) with Ajax to dynamically load elements in the list.

I have an issue as between the initialization of the Select2 (where a url property is set in the ajax helper) and the time the ajax call is made, this url might need to be changed.

So I have something like this :

```js
$box.select2({
    containerCssClass: "form-control"
    minimumInputLength: 0,
    allowClear: true,
    ajax: {
       url: someUrl,
       dataType: 'json',
       quietMillis: 100,
...
}
```

I can't figure out how, when, where to change the `ajax.url` value before it launches.

The help of Select2 says:

> Select2 uses jQuery's `$.ajax` function to execute the remote call by default. An alternative `transport` function can be specified in the `ajax` settings, or an entirely custom implementation can be built by providing a custom `query` function instead of using the ajax helper.

But I can't find any example on how to do it.

Thanks in advance for any help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> I can't figure out how, when, where to change the ajax.url value before it launches.

The `ajax.url` option can be specified as a static string or a method returning one in both Select2 3.5.x and 4.0.0.

```
$("select").select2({
  ajax: {
    url: function () {
      return UrlHelper.RemoteAPI();
    }
  }
});
```

This is useful for changing the *base URL*, for example when the URL is determined at runtime or is automatically generated in a different method. If you need to change the *query parameters*, such as the one used for sending the search term, you need to override the `ajax.data` option.

```
$("select").select2({
  ajax: {
    data: function (args) {
      // args is the search term in 3.5.x

      // args is an object containing the query parameters in 4.0.0
      // args.term is the search term in 4.0.0
      return {
        search: args.term || args;
      };
    }
  }
});
```

The data here will be appended as query parameters by default, and will be sent as the request body if the method type is changed from `GET` (the default) to anything else.

> > Select2 uses jQuery's $.ajax function to execute the remote call by default. An alternative transport function can be specified in the ajax settings, or an entirely custom implementation can be built by providing a custom query function instead of using the ajax helper.
>
> But I can't find any example on how to do it.

Select2 does allow for a different AJAX transport to be used by changing the `ajax.transport` option.

In 3.5.2, this must be a `$.ajax`-compatible method, so it must be able to take an object containing the `success` and `failure` callbacks.

```
$("select").select2({
  ajax: {
    transport: function (args) {
      // args.success is a callback
      // args.failure is a callback

      // should return an object which has an `abort` method.
      return $.ajax(args);
    }
  }
});
```

In 4.0.0, this must be a method which takes a `params` object (the same one passed to `ajax.data`), a `success` callback, and a `failure` callback.

```
$("select").select2({
  ajax: {
    transport: function (params, success, failure) {
      var $request = $.ajax(params);

      $request.then(success);
      $request.fail(failure);

      return $request;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You saved my life.

Comment: You also saved my life.

Answer (score 4):

Very Simple Javascript code to handle the same, can be used in Suitescript(Netsuite) also.

```
// prepare your dynamic URL inside this method and return
function getURL() {
     return url + params;
}

// While binding the select2 with the dropdown set url to call a anonymous function which internally calls another function.
jQuery("select.itemDropDown").select2({
    placeholder: "Select an item",
    width: "200px",
    minimumInputLength: 3,
    ajax: {
        url: function() {
            return getURL()
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before you can use a function to dynamically generate the URL, in this example I am adding the search parameter as part of the URL.

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#country-select').select2({
                minimumInputLength: 1,
                ajax: {
                    url: function (params) {
                        return 'https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/' + encodeURIComponent(params.term) + '?fullText=false';
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    delay: 250,
                    data: function (params) {
                        return {
                            name: params.term,
                            fullText: true
                        };
                    },
                    processResults: function (data) {
                        return {
                            results: $.map(data, function (country) {
                                return {
                                    id: country.name.common,
                                    text: country.name.common
                                }
                            })
                        };
                    },
                    cache: true
                },
                placeholder: 'Select a country',
                allowClear: true
            });
        });
```

```css
.select2-container {
            width: 250px !important ;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Country Selector</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/css/select2.min.css"  />
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.1.0-rc.0/js/select2.min.js" ></script>

</head>
<body>
    <select id="country-select"></select>
</body>
</html>
```